# Inner Join de Consultas

Tags: postgresql, sql

Les comento, yo tengo una query que tiene una consulta que me trae determinados idusuarios sometidos a determinadas condiciones, y tengo otra consulta con otros `idusuarios` sometidos a otras condiciones, por lo que tendría

```
CONSULTA 1: XXX idusuarios
CONSULTA 2: XXX idusuarios
```

Mi pregunta es: ¿Hay alguna manera de hacer un `INNER JOIN` de esas consultas, trayendo solamente donde coinciden los `idusuarios` ?

Comment: Podrías adjuntar a tu pregunta ambas consultas para hacernos poder orientarte mejor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tal vez puede ayudarte algo como esto:

```
select
    *
from
    schema.table1 a
    inner join schema.table2 b on (a.id_usuario=b.id_usuario)
```